# Actions vs PlannedActions: do I need a new resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, architecture, cucumber

I have an app which allows users to input Actions (25 minute time blocks).  I'm using Ruby on Rails, but for now I'm just trying to describe the behavior I want with Cucumber.

For a long time, I've only allowed users to create an Action for THIS time block (an Action always has to start on the half-hour).

However, now I'd like to add Planned Actions.  The only difference would be a status (incomplete) and it would take a date (planned for which day) instead of a datetime.  Then the user would have a choice of creating a new NOW Action or a PLANNED Action (chosen from the available Planned Actions for that day).

Is this a case where I need to create a new resource?  More generally, how do I know whether I need to add a new model, new controller or neither?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to put everything about Object-Oriented Design in one post, but I can try.

Long ago it was explained to me like this:

> Classes is all about behaviour. You can't define a new class or subclass every time you add some stupid field. You should be guided by lazyness and common sense (mostly). So, if you tell me that Sun is a subclass for Circle... I don't want to live in a world like this.

Basically, you need to think about your models in terms of their behaviour. In Rails, they follow [active record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). They combine features of data storage and business logic. So, if there's a big difference between Planned Actions and simple Actions (not in terms of data, but in terms of different way of behaving, processing and etc.), you need a new model for that.

Controllers themselves are pretty identical from resource to resource and some of us use gems like [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) to write less code. Generally, there's a controller for every kind of resource in your application.

I hope it answers your question. At least a bit of it.

***Update***.

Let's dance around your example (Actions / Planned Actions). 
You've added `status` field and replaced `datetime` by `date` (it actually changes almost nothing). So, it is quite possible that you've added a new trait - `status` field and tracking current state of the action. I believe there will be some logic for starting such actions, following their progress or something else. That aspect, of *action which can be started, stopped and tracked in progress* is quite different from traits of a simple `Action`. Even one function, one *aspect* of behaviour is enough, to extract that functionality into a separate class.

You can think of objects as a projection of objects from a real world. `Action` is an abstract concept, and you've selected some traits of it to present in your application (ignoring everything else).

When you introduce `PlannedAction`, you need to think about traits you want it to have. Can `PlannedAction` be just an `Action` in some cases (for example, you need to display some kind of schedule of all actions for a given date)?

If you see that `PlannedAction` needs to be a substitute for `Action` in some cases, you need to inherit `PlannedAction` from `Action`. Base class will never know about `status` field and everything like that, but will provide basic functionality to `PlannedAction`.

However, if `PlannedAction` is too different from a simple `Action` (different use cases and behaviour) you might consider to make `PlannedAction` a separate class, without inhertance at all.

After numerous tries and failures, you will find yourself *feeling* that, for example, `Car` has a long way from `MetalSlug` and shouldn't inherit from it. But `Car` is not quite far from `Truck`, and they can possibly have a common parent - `Vehicle`.

Comment: Thanks, that does help a bit.  But without a ton of experience, how can I judge whether there's a big difference?  For example, write a number of behaviors, and if 30% are different that's big?

Comment: Updated my answer. Just in case you've missed it.